# python how to create many-to-many of lists inside one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have variable like this :

```
message = "hello world"
```

and I want to put each 2 letters inside one list like this:

```
list = [['h', 'e'], ['l', 'l'], ...]
```

I have tried this method:

```
message = "hello world"
x,test = 0,[[]] * len(message)
for i in message:
   if len(test[x]) >= 2:
      x += 1
      test[x].append(i)
   else:
      test[x].append(i)
```

but the result was adding hello world for every list.

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/14429185).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your outer list contains a reference to a single inner list, just repeated. You can see what I mean by taking your resulting `test` and reassigning the value of one of the elements:

```py
>>> test[1][0] = 9999
[[9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
 [9999, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']]
```

So even though `x` is incrementing, you're still just appending to a single list object because your `test` variable is a list of repeated references to the same object.

You can get around this by using a comprehension to initialize your `test` variable:

```py
test = [[] for _ in range(len(message))]
```

You can also use `zip` and slicing to get what you want in a single line of code:

```py
[[*z] for z in zip(s[0::2], s[1::2])]
```